# C# Run Another Program and Specify App.Config File

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I have a test program in which I'm calling another program (let's call this the main program) with `System.Diagnostics`. I'm having issues specifying which `App.Config` the test program is using. It seems to always default to using the main program's `app.config`. Is there a way to specify which file to use without changing the main program to use program arguments? See my code below.

```
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.FileName = @"...\MainProgram.exe";
  process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
  process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"...\TestProgram\bin\Debug";
  process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can copy the file you want to use to ensure that it is the one you need.

Use `File.Copy` to accomplish that.

```
  File.Copy(@"C:\yourCorrectFilePath\App.Config", @"...\TestProgram\bin\Debug\App.Config", true);
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.FileName = @"...\MainProgram.exe";
  process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
  process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"...\TestProgram\bin\Debug";
  process.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, your Idea works. I've copied my test app.config over to the programs directory, I may change it in the future to copy the main program's directory into a temp directory instead of editing the Main Program's app.config.

Comment: Please note that this does not work for user settings. They are stored in separate XML files within the user profile somewhere. Also the config file is not called app.config for the compiled application, but matches the assembly name + "exe.config". So the above code only works when modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could start the program in a separate app domain and set the path to the app.config form there:

```
      AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
                    {
                        ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
                        LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost,
                        ApplicationBase = "C:\ExamplePath",
                        PrivateBinPath = "C:\ExamplePath",
                        PrivateBinPathProbe = "C:\ExamplePath"
                    };

                    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ExampleName", null, setup);
                    domain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "C:\ExamplePath" + "\\app.config");

setup.ExecuteAssembly(@"c:\ExamplePath\MainProgram.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the App.config file at run time. @NicoRiff's answer will work but you can also store the executable with the different configs at different paths which can be set to a variable programmatically.